# Visual Studio Performance Profiling : JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, profiling

I'm using the Performance Wizard in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  I have selected Instrumentation and the type of profiling  JavaScript for my Web Project. When I Launch the wizard I receive the error:

PRF0005: Launch Error Unable to execute (iexplore.exe).
Any Ideas anyone. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a firewall problem, Either disable it or make an exception in your firewall. If you have McAfee, Check to see if you have McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention turned on, check activity logs to see it there is a time that matches the time you tried to launch the wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Got same error on C# desktop project. If WebProject have manifest, possible reason is

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />`
```

so solution is

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`
```